# Set CXX-standard to c++17 when combining C++ and CUDA in CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

According to the documentation of CMake I just have to write

```
project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
```

when I would like to combine CUDA-files and native C++-files in one project. Then I do not have to call `cuda_add_executable()` anymore, but rather `add_executable`, and CMake should figure out everything on its own. This works fine, unless I would like to specify a standard for C++-code (by using `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`). Then I get the error message

```
Target requires the language dialect "CUDA17" (with compiler extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it
```

Is there an alternative solution, or should I rather revert to `find_package(CUDA)` and `cuda_add_executable`?

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19123

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the comment from @talonmies I found a solution for that problem by setting the variables explicitly for each language, i.e. `CUDA` and `CXX`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
```

Now the pure `C++`-files are compiled according to C++17, and the `CUDA`-files are compiled according to C++14.