# CMake cannot set CUDA standard c++17

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, c++17

I'm using CMake to configure a CUDA/C++ project. Some of the files compiled with NVCC require C++ 17 features. To enable those, I would use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(RISA LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)
```

which results in an error message:

`Target "RISA" requires the language dialect "CUDA17" (with compiler extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.`

Double checking the `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILE_FEATURES` variable reveals `cuda_std_03 cuda_std_11 cuda_std_14`. For some reason, CMake doesn't seem to know about anything past C++14 regarding CUDA.

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 with

- NVCC 11.2
- GCC 10.1.0
- CMake 3.19.6

What can I do to get C++17 configured and compiled with this setup?

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540127/set-cxx-standard-to-c17-when-combining-c-and-cuda-in-cmakelists) question - however the solution to just compile cuda files with C++14 does not suffice for me.

Comment: Have you tried [`CUDA_STANDARD`instead](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/prop_tgt/CUDA_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CUDA_STANDARD)?

Comment: @KenY-N Just did, exact same result.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_tgt/CUDA_STANDARD.html), support for CUDA standards 17 and later has been added in CMake 3.18. Are you sure that you use CMake 3.19? The last CMake package for Ubuntu 20.04 is CMake 3.16: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cmake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I've built it from source for this exact reason. I've even switched to 3.21.2 just now (confirmed by `message(${CMAKE_VERSION}`) - still no success. I can only guess there is some global cmake stuff somewhere which conflicts the newer version.

Comment: Oh, actually the message "CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it" does NOT mean that CMake is *unaware* about given feature (CUDA17). The message means that CMake is **aware** about the feature, but it doesn't know how to apply this feature to the compiler which you **actually have**. Have you checked that CMake finds exactly NVCC 11.2, and that given compiler supports C++17?

Comment: Oh, thanks, that might be it! CMake tells me `The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.1.243` even though the `CUDA_VERSION` was detected to 11.2. Also, the `CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE` points to version 11.2. And yes, the installed nvcc can compile the cu file just fine with flag `std=c++17`. I'll double check where CMake gets the cuda compiler identification from...

Comment: Well, who would have guessed, there's another path to set: `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER` which pointed to the old version. It works now, thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps you could self-answer this question as it might be useful to someone else?

Comment: @Dominic: I have reopened this so you can now add an answer to help future visitors with the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is turns out, CMake was not using the correct `nvcc` binary.

In my case, I've had two versions of nvcc on the system:

- `nvcc v10.1.243` in `/usr/bin` and
- `nvcc v11.2.152` in `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin`

In my CMake configuration,

- `CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE` was set to `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin`, but
- `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER` was set to the older version in `/usr/bin`.

After setting `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER` to the correct path, CMake was able to detect `nvcc 11.2.152` and could apply the C++17 standard.

Comment: to add, I also had to delete /usr/bin/nvcc to get this to work